# Reactive - mixing blocking with asynchronous requests

Tags: java, reactive-programming

I'm playing around with Spring's [reactor-core](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core). We will be using MySQL as the backend which to my understanding doesn't have any non-blocking drivers.

What is the most efficient way to make a query to MySQL as well as a non-blocking HTTP request using reactive WebClient to reduce overall response latency?

Comment: if latency is so important for you, first make sure reactive WebClient is faster than good old synchronous thread-per-client approach.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov we're moving towards a microservice architecture, and it's highly likely a request to our service will result in 2 or more downstream HTTP requests. So even if individual requests are slightly slow using the WebClient if we can make the requests concurrently that would probably see big dividends.

Comment: concurrent actions can be of 2 forms - threads and asynchronous tasks. If MySQL can be accesses only from threads, start a thread. If reactive WebClient supports asynchronous tasks, start tasks. The only difference is how that actions communicate with each other. Exact ways of communications are described in numerous tutorials.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your concerns. Blocking means blocking the thread, but you can decide on which thread(s) the streams run.